# "before initiation of" or "before the initiation of"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

I need some explanation to fully grasp the differences between the following two:

> 1. The guidelines suggest a confirmed diagnosis before initiation of the treatment
> 2. The guidelines suggest a confirmed diagnosis before **the** initiation of the treatment.

Both seem correct to me (are they?) but I feel there are some subtleties that I cannot fully grasp (an illusion?).

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

It's an instance where there are only slight differences among the constructions and where interpretation of the nuances may well differ.

The first option is:

> the guidelines suggest a confirmed diagnosis before initiation of *the* treatment

which implies *any initiation of treatment*, that a specific treatment is recommended and is written (without the first *the*) in a tighter style, more likely to be used by the medical profession;

Your second suggestion:

> the guidelines suggest a confirmed diagnosis before *the* initiation of *the* treatment.

is just more fully written out and suggests that a start for the treatment is already in prospect; it also suggests that a specific treatment is recommended.

but there is no difference in meaning.

The other option, which you have not suggested, is:

> the guidelines suggest (a) confirmed diagnosis before initiation of treatment.

omitting both uses of *the*, which sounds more like typical medical shorthand and leaves open which treatment might be recommended.